# XPath how to check if an ancestor element has a certain name

Tags: java, xpath, attributes, xerces, ancestor

I have an element structure like so:

```
<template>
    <x name="foo">
        <y>
            <x>
                <a>
                    <b number="1" />
                    <c>2</c>
                </a>
            </x>
            <c>5</c>
        </y>
    </x>
</template>
```

I need it so that a `b` element can only exist in `a` as long as one of the ancestors is an `x` with a name.  I have a set of alternatives written, but I can't get the test to work.  This is what I thought would work:

```
ancestor::x[@name]
```

but I get no result.  The only xpath I've had luck with is this:

```
ancestor::node()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Edit:

I'm using a java xerces 2.11 library to load an xsd file which includes  tags.

Comment: Hmm... this XPath able to return result given XML posted : `//b[ancestor::x[@name]]`

Comment: `ancestor::x[@name]` should work given the right context. You'll probably need to show more context in order for us to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below xpath and it gave me proper result. I hope you are using proper context for ancestor element.

```
//template//b/ancestor::x[@name]
```

Output result is as below :

```
Element='<x name="foo">
  <y>
    <x>
      <a>
        <b number="1" />
        <c>2</c>
      </a>
    </x>
    <c>5</c>
  </y>
</x>'
```

As per your condition, the xpath will be :

```
//template//b[ancestor::x[@name]]
```

And the output will be as below which will only be given if it has ancestor element 'x' with name attribute :

```
Element='<b number="1" />'
```